# Changing text by calling javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to change a line of text if a link is clicked, however it doesnt seem to be calling my script to change it.

```
<script >
         var paragraphToChange = document.getElementById("q1");
         paragraphToChange.innerHTML ="Quotation is by:" + <a href="http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/1463.html">Antole France</a>

</script>


 <div id="body">
       <p>javascript.html - JavaScript page</p>
       <a href id="q1">Quotaion is by:</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: you have to do this after the html has been loaded. and where is your click event?

Comment: There is so much wrong with this I don't know where to begin. How about: Why do you think this should do anything at all in response to something being clicked? (You also really, really need to open your browsers developer tools and read the error messages on the console)

Comment: I'm pretty new to this lol, its not showing anything.. im coding it in n++

Comment: Start by studying the simple example given in: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is probably something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="q1">
<a onClick="javascript:clickFunction()">Quotation is by</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
clickFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/1463.html'>Antole France</a>";
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ou7yweam/3/)

Comment: It ends up writing it at the bottom of the original text instead of replacing it.
edit: nvm fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sir you have to set the value of "newValue" to the quotation.

```
    var newValue = '"Quotation is by:" + <a href="http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/1463.html">Antole France</a>'
    paragraphToChange.innerHTML = newValue;
```

Comment: Nope, developer tools returns : Uncaught typeError: cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

in the ' paragraphToChange.innerHTML = newValue;' line

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the click event on the Html tag. Hence, this     `paragraphToChange.innerHTML ="Quotation is by:" + <a href="http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/1463.html">Antole France</a>"` 
never gets call.

Why don't you start with this example first:

```
<p id="display"></p>

<button onclick="displayBob">Bob</button>
<button onclick="displayTom">Tom</button>

<script>
displayBob = function ()
{
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello Bob";
}

displayTom = function ()
{ 
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello Tom";
}
</script>
```

Comment: That won't work, you're not executing the function in the onClick event.

Comment: That was my bad. I edited the example. I should work now